# Invalid JDK path shown on startup

Tags: java, windows

Recently I am using windows 10. In my local machine earlier I installed JDK 7 then, I removed that and installed JDK8 to another location. Also I changed **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** variables.

I have checked my **PATH** variable and **JAVA_HOME**, those are also correct.

Also I checked in the registry, in **LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/JAVASOFT** shows JRE8 path that is also correct.

It shows JDK7 before change the position of **"%JAVA_HOME%\bin"** in the **PATH** variable then, after it shows JDK8 path. But, it shows JDK7 again path when computer is restarted. That means **JAVA_HOME** gets different values according to its position int the path variable.

I have checked everywhere as much as I can. But I couldn't find the **JDK7** path value.

My variables are like this :

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\java\jdk1.8.0_60;
PATH = %SystemRoot%\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%;
```

I am changing the position like this :

```
PATH = %SystemRoot%\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%;
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;
```

Comment: Did you check both system and user environment variables?

Comment: yes, both are correct.

Comment: How exactly are you Changing the values? Where?

Comment: I dont change the values. When I am chaning the position of the %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the path variable, it automatically changes.

Comment: But onece I changed the position, It shows the latest value and it dosent apply for further changes.

Comment: Not sure what you are you saying. Still not sure how you are changing values.

Comment: @AseemBansal, I have added more details about the problem.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10